# Atom editor - linter-scss-lint error

Tags: sass, atom-editor

In Atom editor I would like to use [linter-scss-lint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-scss-lint), but linter is not executed.

I added *.scss-lint.yml* to my home folder and project folder.

**.scss-lint.yml**

```
# Default application configuration that all configurations inherit from.

scss_files: "**/*.scss"
plugin_directories: ['.scss-linters']

# List of gem names to load custom linters from (make sure they are already
# installed)
plugin_gems: []

linters:
  BangFormat:
    enabled: true
    space_before_bang: true
    space_after_bang: false

  BemDepth:
    enabled: false
    max_elements: 1

  BorderZero:
    enabled: true
    convention: zero # or `none`

  ColorKeyword:
    enabled: true

  ColorVariable:
    enabled: true

  Comment:
    enabled: true

  DebugStatement:
    enabled: true

  DeclarationOrder:
    enabled: true

  DisableLinterReason:
    enabled: false

  DuplicateProperty:
    enabled: true

  ElsePlacement:
    enabled: true
    style: same_line # or 'new_line'

  EmptyLineBetweenBlocks:
    enabled: true
    ignore_single_line_blocks: true

  EmptyRule:
    enabled: true

  ExtendDirective:
    enabled: false

  FinalNewline:
    enabled: true
    present: true

  HexLength:
    enabled: true
    style: short # or 'long'

  HexNotation:
    enabled: true
    style: lowercase # or 'uppercase'

  HexValidation:
    enabled: true

  IdSelector:
    enabled: true

  ImportantRule:
    enabled: true

  ImportPath:
    enabled: true
    leading_underscore: false
    filename_extension: false

  Indentation:
    enabled: true
    allow_non_nested_indentation: false
    character: space # or 'tab'
    width: 2

  LeadingZero:
    enabled: true
    style: exclude_zero # or 'include_zero'

  MergeableSelector:
    enabled: true
    force_nesting: true

  NameFormat:
    enabled: true
    allow_leading_underscore: true
    convention: hyphenated_lowercase # or 'camel_case', or 'snake_case', or a regex pattern

  NestingDepth:
    enabled: true
    max_depth: 3
    ignore_parent_selectors: false

  PlaceholderInExtend:
    enabled: true

  PropertyCount:
    enabled: false
    include_nested: false
    max_properties: 10

  PropertySortOrder:
    enabled: false
    ignore_unspecified: false
    min_properties: 2
    separate_groups: false

  PropertySpelling:
    enabled: true
    extra_properties: []
    disabled_properties: []

  PropertyUnits:
    enabled: true
    global: [
      'ch', 'em', 'ex', 'rem',                 # Font-relative lengths
      'cm', 'in', 'mm', 'pc', 'pt', 'px', 'q', # Absolute lengths
      'vh', 'vw', 'vmin', 'vmax',              # Viewport-percentage lengths
      'deg', 'grad', 'rad', 'turn',            # Angle
      'ms', 's',                               # Duration
      'Hz', 'kHz',                             # Frequency
      'dpi', 'dpcm', 'dppx',                   # Resolution
      '%']                                     # Other
    properties: {}

  QualifyingElement:
    enabled: true
    allow_element_with_attribute: false
    allow_element_with_class: false
    allow_element_with_id: false

  SelectorDepth:
    enabled: true
    max_depth: 3

  SelectorFormat:
    enabled: true
    convention: hyphenated_lowercase # or 'strict_BEM', or 'hyphenated_BEM', or 'snake_case', or 'camel_case', or a regex pattern

  Shorthand:
    enabled: true
    allowed_shorthands: [1, 2, 3]

  SingleLinePerProperty:
    enabled: true
    allow_single_line_rule_sets: true

  SingleLinePerSelector:
    enabled: true

  SpaceAfterComma:
    enabled: true

  SpaceAfterPropertyColon:
    enabled: true
    style: one_space # or 'no_space', or 'at_least_one_space', or 'aligned'

  SpaceAfterPropertyName:
    enabled: true

  SpaceAfterVariableName:
    enabled: true

  SpaceAroundOperator:
    enabled: true
    style: one_space # or 'no_space'

  SpaceBeforeBrace:
    enabled: true
    style: space # or 'new_line'
    allow_single_line_padding: false

  SpaceBetweenParens:
    enabled: true
    spaces: 0

  StringQuotes:
    enabled: true
    style: single_quotes # or double_quotes

  TrailingSemicolon:
    enabled: true

  TrailingWhitespace:
    enabled: true

  TrailingZero:
    enabled: false

  TransitionAll:
    enabled: false

  UnnecessaryMantissa:
    enabled: true

  UnnecessaryParentReference:
    enabled: true

  UrlFormat:
    enabled: true

  UrlQuotes:
    enabled: true

  VariableForProperty:
    enabled: false
    properties: []

  VendorPrefix:
    enabled: true
    identifier_list: base
    additional_identifiers: []
    excluded_identifiers: []

  ZeroUnit:
    enabled: true

  Compass::*:
    enabled: false
```

I added linter settings to **config.cson**

```
"linter-scss-lint":
    disableWhenNoConfigFileInPath: false
    executablePath: "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/scss_lint-0.42.2/bin/scss-lint"
```

When I open scss file I get error:

```
Error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- scss_lint (LoadError) from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:inrequire' from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/scss_lint-0.42.2/bin/scss-lint:3:in `

'

Error: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- scss_lint (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/scss_lint-0.42.2/bin/scss-lint:3:in `<main>'
    at parameters.exit (/Users/and/.atom/packages/linter-scss-lint/node_modules/atom-linter/lib/helpers.js:74:20)
    at triggerExitCallback (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:213:47)
    at /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:220:18
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/buffered-process.js:98:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Pipe._onclose (net.js:469:12)
```

Comment: Seems like it's going to be looking for `.sass-lint.yml` where you mention you're using `.scss-lint.yml`. What happens when you change the file name to what it (by default) is expecting to find?

Comment: You are right. I didn't notice this. I created new file .sass-lint.yml in home folder. Now I have .sass-lint.yml and .scss-lint.yml in my home folder. I set path to /Users/and/.sass-lint.yml, restarted Atom, but linter still doesn't lint.

Comment: Keep in mind my experience is with SCSS-Lint not Sass so most of these are just educated guesses.

I had a problem putting them in my home folder but I have a Projects folder where all my work lives and keeping it in _that_ folder does work for me. I'd try something similar where you put it in the specific project first to see if it loads and move it out to parent folders until you find the breaking point.

Does it give any errors or it just isn't linting?

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you don't use RVM? I have a `.scss-lint.yml` file in my projects folder and an exec. path of `/Users/greg/.rvm/bin/atom_scss-lint` as I use RVM and it seems to work fine. Have you confirmed that the exec. path you're giving it "exists"? And have you tried not setting the executable path? I'd keep an eye on the bug tracker for it (https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-scss-lint/issues) as a few other people have had similar issues.

Comment: I don't use RVM, because I don't have .rvm folder. If executable path is not set (is default), I get error `Failed to spawn command scss-lint. Make sure scss-lint is installed and on your PATH`. I am sure exec. path is correct, because when I run in terminal `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/scss_lint-0.42.2/bin/scss-lint` `path to scss file`, it works. Thanks for help, I will check issues and maybe open one.

Comment: This question linked to [this issue](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-scss-lint/issues/81)

Answer (score 1):

for linter-scss-lint works you need customize the package in Settings.

File >> Settings >> Packages >> linter-scss-lint

Then, in **config name** you put

default.yml

and **executable path** put

C:\Ruby23-x64\bin\scss-lint

Ready, this works for me.

Regrads.